# .net core with httpclient request delete and body

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

I need to pass one parameter throught body while Im calling HttpMethod:DELETE

Im getting as response: method not allowed (403)

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Delete,
    RequestUri = new Uri($"{_iOptions.Server}{_iOptions.Method.DeleteAllKeys}")
};

request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{ \"umcn\": " + umcn + " }"));
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false); 
// here in responseMessage error code is: System.Net.HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed

responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

GeneralResponseModel response = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<GeneralResponseModel>();

if (response.Code == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    response.Success = true;
    return response;
}
else
{
    response.Success = false;
    return response;
};
```

umcn property is represents a string value.

Comment: _response: method not allowed (403)_ - is this actually a [403](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_HttpStatusCode_Forbidden) ("forbidden") with that text, or is it actually a [405](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_HttpStatusCode_MethodNotAllowed) ("method not allowed")?

Comment: If you are seeing: "method not allowed (403)"  what seems to be the problem? Do you really think it is your code that is wrong?  Or maybe a HTTP server which says you do not have permission?

Comment: @stuartd its exactly 405 ("method not allowed").

Comment: yes, I think its it up to the server..for some reason I cant do delete thing..

Comment: @Stefan0309,  Did you send the token to the server? What authentication framework is used on the server?